# java.lang.RuntimeException - no solution is working

Tags: android, eclipse, runtime-error

i get this error log if i'm running my app with eclipse on my testing phone.

Can you tell me what i have to do? I read a lot of "solutions" but nothing worked for me.

```
10-09 11:49:28.953: E/AndroidRuntime(5552): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-09 11:49:28.953: E/AndroidRuntime(5552): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{stealthychief.icon.pack.retro/stealthychief.icon.pack.retro.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "stealthychief.icon.pack.retro.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/stealthychief.icon.pack.retro-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/stealthychief.icon.pack.retro-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
10-09 11:49:28.953: E/AndroidRuntime(5552):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2255)
10-09 11:49:28.953: E/AndroidRuntime(5552):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2389)
10-09 11:49:28.953: E/AndroidRuntime(5552):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:153)
10-09 11:49:28.953: E/AndroidRuntime(5552):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1269)
10-09 11:49:28.953: E/AndroidRuntime(5552):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-09 11:49:28.953: E/AndroidRuntime(5552):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-09 11:49:28.953: E/AndroidRuntime(5552):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5289)
10-09 11:49:28.953: E/AndroidRuntime(5552):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-09 11:49:28.953: E/AndroidRuntime(5552):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-09 11:49:28.953: E/AndroidRuntime(5552):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
10-09 11:49:28.953: E/AndroidRuntime(5552):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
10-09 11:49:28.953: E/AndroidRuntime(5552):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-09 11:49:28.953: E/AndroidRuntime(5552): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "stealthychief.icon.pack.retro.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/stealthychief.icon.pack.retro-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/stealthychief.icon.pack.retro-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
10-09 11:49:28.953: E/AndroidRuntime(5552):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
10-09 11:49:28.953: E/AndroidRuntime(5552):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
10-09 11:49:28.953: E/AndroidRuntime(5552):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
10-09 11:49:28.953: E/AndroidRuntime(5552):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
10-09 11:49:28.953: E/AndroidRuntime(5552):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2246)
10-09 11:49:28.953: E/AndroidRuntime(5552):     ... 11 more
```

Here is my android manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest android:versionCode="14" android:versionName="2.1.3" android:installLocation="auto" package="stealthychief.icon.pack.retro"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER_HINTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <application android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/theme_icon" android:allowBackup="true">
        <meta-data android:name="in.vineetsirohi.uccwtheme" android:value="2" />
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="stealthychief.icon.pack.retro.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:label="@string/blank" android:name="stealthychief.icon.pack.retro.activities.ActivityDump" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:noHistory="true" android:parentActivityName="stealthychief.icon.pack.retro.MainActivity">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" android:value=".MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="stealthychief.icon.pack.retro.GetActivities" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:noHistory="true" android:parentActivityName="stealthychief.icon.pack.retro.MainActivity">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" android:value=".MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:theme="@*android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" android:name="stealthychief.icon.pack.retro.StartupHelper" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:noHistory="true" android:parentActivityName="stealthychief.icon.pack.retro.MainActivity">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" android:value=".MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/theme_icon" android:name="stealthychief.icon.pack.retro.Wallpaper" android:screenOrientation="nosensor" android:finishOnCloseSystemDialogs="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SET_WALLPAPER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/theme_icon" android:name=".ADW">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="org.adw.launcher.icons.ACTION_PICK_ICON" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="org.adw.launcher.THEMES" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="com.anddoes.launcher.THEME" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="com.gau.go.launcherex.theme" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:theme="@*android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" android:label="@string/icons_title" android:icon="@drawable/theme_icon" android:name="stealthychief.icon.pack.retro.Icons" android:noHistory="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE" />
                <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:label="@string/blank" android:name=".ZoomActivity" android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" android:value=".MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:label="@string/blank" android:name="stealthychief.icon.pack.retro.uccw" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:noHistory="true" android:parentActivityName="stealthychief.icon.pack.retro.MainActivity">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" android:value=".MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:label="@string/blank" android:name="stealthychief.icon.pack.retro.UccwSkins" android:parentActivityName="stealthychief.icon.pack.retro.MainActivity">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" android:value=".MainActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Thanks for you help :)

Comment: Could you show us the first line of your MainActivity: package ....

Comment: check your, package names, class names, and package declaration.

Comment: At the  time of declaration of package in manifest file just check dot(.) is perfectly placed or not..?

Comment: sorry for that, but i'm a greenhorn in android developmet. Can you tell me where i find the MainActivity package? And what exactly do you mean with "check you package names..."?

Maybe i have to say that i decompile the .apk file with AndroidMultitool, than i imported it to eclipse, run it and i get this error. So the app is working, but it didn't if i decompile it

Comment: did you mean this line? ".class public Lstealthychief/icon/pack/retro/MainActivity;"

Comment: can nobody help me out?